Multiplayer game in Unity riddled with seemingly unsolvable errors: type or namespace Unity Transport not found, and scripts not attachable to gameobj
I'm making a multiplayer game in Unity, and I've started by implementing the multiplayer feature itself. After making good progress, I get an error telling me that type or namespace UnityTransport can't be found. After trying to solve it and making no permanent changes to my project, suddenly I can't attach the scripts to any gameobject, because "It doesn't include MonoBehaviour or the names don't match".
Here are the three scripts that are used (the other two aren't used anywhere yet, they're imported from another project and work perfectly fine there):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    public float speed;

    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner)
        {
            return;
        }

        float forwInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float horzInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward * forwInput + Vector3.right * horzInput;
        if (direction.magnitude > 1) { direction.Normalize(); }

        MoveServerRpc(direction);
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    void MoveServerRpc(Vector3 direction)
    {
        playerRb.AddForce(direction * speed);
    }
}

Second:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using Unity.Netcode.Transports.UTP;


[System.Serializable]
public struct PlayerNetworkState : INetworkSerializable
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Rotation;

    public void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer) where T : IReaderWriter
    {
        serializer.SerializeValue(ref Position);
        serializer.SerializeValue(ref Rotation);
    }
}


public class PlayerNetwork : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private bool usingServerAuth;
    private NetworkVariable<PlayerNetworkState> playerState;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        var permission = usingServerAuth ? NetworkVariableWritePermission.Server : NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner;
        playerState = new NetworkVariable<PlayerNetworkState>(new PlayerNetworkState {Position = Vector3.zero, Rotation = Vector3.zero}, NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone, permission);
    }

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) Destroy(transform.GetComponent<Player>());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsOwner) TransmitState();
        else ConsumeState();
    }

    #region Transmit State

    private void TransmitState()
    {
        var state = new PlayerNetworkState
        {
            Position = playerRb.position,
            Rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles
        };

        if (IsServer || !usingServerAuth)
        {
            playerState.Value = state;
        }
        else
        {
            TransmitStateServerRpc(state);
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void TransmitStateServerRpc(PlayerNetworkState state)
    {
        playerState.Value = state;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Consume State

    private void ConsumeState()
    {
        transform.position = playerState.Value.Position;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(playerState.Value.Rotation);
    }

    #endregion
}

Third:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;

public class NetworkButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(10,10,300,300));
        if (!NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient && !NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer) {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Host")) NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Server")) NetworkManager.Singleton.StartServer();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Client")) NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
        }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }

    private void OnAwake() 
    {
        GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetDebugSimulatorParameters(
            packetDelay: 120, 
            packetJitter: 5, 
            dropRate: 3);
    }   
}

I've updated Netcode and Unity Transport packages to their latest versions (1.5.2 and 2.3.0 respectively). I did include using Unity.Netcode.Transports.UTP;. This is my first project, so my experience is basically zero, so if this is a dumb question, sorry! I just haven't found any solutions online. If you need any other info or screenshots, I'll be happy to provide them.
Screenshot

The error in your screenshot is in your NetworkButtons.cs. Can you post the contents of this file? Highly likely you have no proper using there.  "It doesn't include MonoBehaviour or the names don't match" - name of the file and name of the class should match, and there should be only one MonoBehaviour in the file.

are you sure you imported the packages for netgame objects?

@Vladimir I completely forgot about that script! I didn't think it was problematic since it's just some UI for Start Host, Server and Client but here, I added it to the post.

I added using Unity.Netcode.Transports.UTP; to the NetworkButtons script, I had no idea it also needed it! Thanks a lot, that solved both problems!

Make sure the class inherits from either MonoBehaviour or NetworkBehaviour and that the file name and class name match. It is case-sensitive.

I'd recommend to use a proper IDE which should have suggested the correct using statements ...
